# Hide "add to cart" button on Catalog, keep "add to cart" button when viewing single item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the following code into the Additional CSS but nothing is changing.

I have tried adding it into the function.php theme file as well and it didn't do anything.

```
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons{
if( is_product_category(acrylic_painting) || is_shop(online_gallery_shop_page)) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
      }
```

The current error I have with this code is: **`Expected RBRACE at Line 2 col.`**

I have added this in but then there are more errors that show up.

Comment: Could you please clean up that code snippet so that it is easier to read. You can wrap the code in "```" and it will break it into a code block and then adding newline and indentation will help following the code logic. From that error though, it seems to be a missing brace/bracket

Comment: _“I have added this in but then there are more errors that show up.”_ – which we are going to _guess_ now, or what …? Please go read [ask] first of all, and then edit your question, so that it includes some info that is actually useful.

Comment: _“and it didn't do anything”_ - simply _declaring_ a function never “does” anything, the function also needs to be _called_ at some point.

Comment: I have never worked with code before, I apologize for not displaying my question correctly. I am trying to remove the add to cart button from the catalog page but still have it available to use when a customer clicks on the item from the catalog and is viewing the single item. Should I be adding coding into the theme or Additional CSS. When I say that it didn't do anything, what I mean is that I entered in the code above to Additional CSS and no changes were made to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket/brace ( '}' ) at the end. It would be better if you shared all the details of your problem first though so we know what exactly is the problem.

```
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    if( is_product_category(acrylic_painting) || is_shop(online_gallery_shop_page) ) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );
```